# Magento 1 : Remove subcategories from url

Tags: magento-1.9, frontend, url

Working on magento 1.9 (CE) website.

i have many categories and sub-categories but that makes url too long can i modify the same as below, if yes can anyone please help.

Below is the category tree
Saree -> By Fabric -> Chiffon

current url : https://www.i-ranu.com/sarees-for-womens/by-fabric/chiffon-sarees-for-womens

i want to make url of all urls : https://www.i-ranu.com/chiffon-sarees-for-womens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your magento version is not latest

```
Go to the Magento Admin Panel -> System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Seo Options

Select yes or no from "Use Parent Category Path for Category URLs"

Refresh category url index
```

Option YES => http://www.example.com/category/subcategory.html

Option NO => http://www.example.com/subcategory.html

> Programatically Solution :-

**To remove parent category path from child category url**
Rewrite class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Url`
override method `public function getCategoryRequestPath($category, $parentPath)` like below

```
public function getCategoryRequestPath($category, $parentPath)
    {
        $storeId = $category->getStoreId();
        $idPath  = $this->generatePath('id', null, $category);
        $suffix  = $this->getCategoryUrlSuffix($storeId);

        if (isset($this->_rewrites[$idPath])) {
            $this->_rewrite = $this->_rewrites[$idPath];
            $existingRequestPath = $this->_rewrites[$idPath]->getRequestPath();
        }

        if ($category->getUrlKey() == '') {
            $urlKey = $this->getCategoryModel()->formatUrlKey($category->getName());
        }
        else {
            $urlKey = $this->getCategoryModel()->formatUrlKey($category->getUrlKey());
        }

        $categoryUrlSuffix = $this->getCategoryUrlSuffix($category->getStoreId());
        // Code commented to remove parent category path from child category path
        //if (null === $parentPath) {
            //$parentPath = $this->getResource()->getCategoryParentPath($category);
        //}
        //elseif ($parentPath == '/') {
            $parentPath = '';
        //}
        $parentPath = Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getCategoryUrlPath($parentPath,
                                                                           true, $category->getStoreId());

        $requestPath = $parentPath . $urlKey . $categoryUrlSuffix;
        if (isset($existingRequestPath) && $existingRequestPath == $requestPath . $suffix) {
            return $existingRequestPath;
        }

        if ($this->_deleteOldTargetPath($requestPath, $idPath, $storeId)) {
            return $requestPath;
        }

        return $this->getUnusedPath($category->getStoreId(), $requestPath,
                                    $this->generatePath('id', null, $category)
        );
    }
```

Modified below code

```
if (null === $parentPath) {
            $parentPath = $this->getResource()->getCategoryParentPath($category);
        }
        elseif ($parentPath == '/') {
            $parentPath = '';
        }
```

to

```
//if (null === $parentPath) {
            //$parentPath = $this->getResource()->getCategoryParentPath($category);
        //}
        //elseif ($parentPath == '/') {
            $parentPath = '';
        //}
```

Comment: i tried to change the codes as per this but still am facing the same problem. please help

Comment: what kind of error you have facing ?

Comment: am not facing any error, i changed the same as provided and refreshed and cleared the cahe but still am unable to remove the subcategary path